# How do you work with the space of circles on the sphere considered as the projective line?

Tags: geometry, differential-topology, projective-geometry

I'm trying to prove some things about the action of the Möbius group on the "circlines" in the extended complex plane, ie. circles on $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

I find that while I have a good grip on Möbius transformations (as $PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$), I don't really know how I'm supposed to treat circles.

Points on the sphere are lines in $\mathbb{C}^2$, so I'm wondering if there's a way to represent circles as things in $\mathbb{C}^2$. More concretely, let $X$ be a circle in $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and $\pi : \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus 0 \to \mathbb{C}P^1$ the quotient map. What is $\pi^{-1}(X)$?

**EDIT**: Many thanks to John Hughes for helping me figure out some of the earlier parts of my question:

> Abstractly speaking, is the space of circles on the sphere a manifold?
>   Or maybe some sort of space with singularities? What dimension is it?
>   How do I work with it?

It seems that circles on the sphere do in fact form a manifold which is double covered by $S^2 \times (-1,1)$ or $S^2 \times [-1,1]$ depending on whether degenerate circles (=points) are allowed. The space of circles is one of the above manifolds quotiented by the relation $(x,y) \sim (-x,-y)$. The quotient of the former becomes a manifold, and the quotient of the latter becomes a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're either talking about great circles or circles of nonzero radius, then yes, the space of circles on a sphere is a manifold.

To make sure I don't screw things up, I'm going to talk about the case of great circles on a *real* sphere, because that has all the features you care about. In this case, each great circle corresponds nicely to a normal line to the plane of the circle, so you've got a correspondence between the space of great circles and $RP^n$. If the circles are oriented, then you get a correspondence with $S^n$.

For all circles (but I'll restrict to nonzero radius, and oriented circles), you have the following correspondence: your circle lies in an oriented plane with an oriented unit normal vector $v$. For any point $P$ of the circle, $ t = (P - C) \cdot v$ tells how far this plane is from the sphere's center, $C$. Alternatively, given $v$ and $t$, you can reconstruct the circle. So this gives a 1-1 correspondence between your set of circles and $S^2 \times (-1, 1)$. 
$$
\newcommand{\ii}{\mathbf i}
$$
Your central question: if $X$ is a circle in $S^2 = \mathbb CP^1$, and points of $S^2$ correspond to lines in $\mathbb C^2$, what does a circle in $S^2$ correspond to? Well...to a family of lines in $\mathbb C^2$. Let's look at the equator as an example. Under stereographic projection from the north pole, this corresponds to the unit circle in $\mathbb C$. Each point $z = \cos t + \ii \sin t$ of the circle corresponds to the line in $\mathbb C^2$ that passes through the point $(z, 1)$. So the preimage of this circle, in 
$\mathbb C^2 \setminus 0$, is $$\{ (  a\cos t + \ii a\sin t, a) \mid t \in \mathbb R, a \in \mathbb C \setminus 0 \}.$$

This is sort of a "double cone" in $\mathbb C^2$, with its apex at the origin, except that each of the ruling lines or "generators" of the cone is a complex line (i.e., a plane) rather than a 1-dimensional line.

Comment: I guess the space $S^2 \times (-1,1)$ is in a 2-1 correspondence with my circles, (a double cover hopefully).


This is helpful, but I can't seem to figure out how to use it to find $\pi^{-1}(X)$.


Also, I feel like you're misinterpreting the role of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ in my question.

Comment: Yes. For unoriented circles, there's the double cover from $S^2 \times (-1, 1)$ to a line bundle over $RP^2$ (but the line bundle is not $RP^2 \times (-1, 1)$ -- it's a twisted line bundle, in much the same way that a Mobius strip looks like a product of a circle and an interval ... but isn't, quite. In fact, if you consider the part of the bundle corresponding *only* to directions that are on the equator of the sphere (i.e., circles in planes parallel to ones containing the polar axis) then you get a mobius-band--worth of circles.

Comment: Dear John Hughes, Thank you for the continued updates as I struggle to phrase what my actual goal is.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**. A circline of $\mathbb{C}$ corresponds in $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to the zero locus of a nonzero hermitian quadratic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (defined up to scalar multiples) with $\det\le0$ (the degenerate circlines correspond to $\det=0$).

Indeed, for the quadratic equation $|w-p|^2=r^2$ (where $p$ is the center and $r$ the radius), we may replace $w$ with $w/z$ to work projectively (recall $[w:z]$ in $(\mathbb{C}^2)^\times/\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{CP}^1$ corresponds to $w/z$ in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\sqcup\{\infty\}$), and rewrite $|w-pz|^2=r^2|z|^2$ (using $|z|^2=\overline{z}z$) as $\overline{w}w-p\overline{w}z-\overline{p}w\overline{z}-r^2\overline{z}z=0$, or in matrix form

$$ \begin{bmatrix} w \\ z \end{bmatrix}^\dagger
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & p \\ \overline{p} & |p|^2-r^2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} w \\ z \end{bmatrix}=0 $$

Thus, the circle $C(p,r)$ corresponds to the hermitian matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&p\\ \overline{p}&|p|^2-r^2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ (or scale by $\frac{1}{r}$ to get $\det=-1$). It may not be clear what to do for actual lines, but notice circlines (circles and lines) in $\mathbb{C}$ correspond in $\mathbb{CP}^1\simeq S^2$ via stereographic projection to just all circles (lines correspond to circles through the north pole, the point of projection). Recall the formulas for stereographic projection are

$$ [\alpha:\beta] \mapsto \left(\frac{\mathrm{Re}(\alpha\overline{\beta})}{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2},\frac{\mathrm{Im}(\alpha\overline{\beta})}{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2},\frac{|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2}{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2}\right), \quad (x,y,z)\mapsto\frac{x+yi}{1-z}. $$

Consider a spherical circle with center $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)\in S^2$ and spherical radius $\theta$. (Note the stereographic projection of $u$ generically does not correspond to the center of the stereographcially projected circle.) The points $\vec{u}=(u,v,w)$ on the spherical circle $SC(\vec{x},\theta)$ are defined by the dot product $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{x}=\cos\theta$.

**Exercise**. Show the $\vec{u}\in SC(\vec{x},\theta)$ correspond to $[\alpha:\beta]\in\mathbb{CP}^1$ which is the zero locus of the hermitian quadratic form defined by the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} z-\cos\theta & x+yi \\ x-yi & -z-\cos\theta \end{smallmatrix}\right]$, where $\vec{x}=(x,y,z)$.

Denote $Q_0=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} z-\cos\theta & x+yi \\ x-yi & -z-\cos\theta \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $Q_\theta=Q_0-(\cos\theta)I_2$. Defining $n(\vec{x})=\left[\begin{smallmatrix} x+yi \\ 1-z\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, the eigenvalues of $Q_0$ are $\pm1$ with respective eigenvectors $n(\pm\vec{x})$. When $\sin\theta=0$ (i.e. $\cos\theta=\pm1$), $Q_\theta$ is (up to a scaling factor of $2$) a projection onto $n(-\vec{x})$, and otherwise we can normalize $\hat{Q}=(\csc\theta)Q_\theta$ in which case $\det\hat{Q}=-1$ and the eigenvalues are $\tan(\theta/2)$ and $-\cot(\theta/2)$ by half-angle formulas.

Importantly, every nonzero hermitian matrix with $\det\le0$ corresponds (up to scaling) to exactly one (possibly degenerate) circle on the Riemann sphere. The effect of Mobius transformations corresponds to similarity transformations of the hermitian matrices (**exercise** - why?).